# Would a truly physical oscillation still be measured in hertz?

Tags: units, frequency, oscillators

I recently bought a new scroll saw and was commenting to someone about how it was a relatively slow saw... low ... RPMs (thinking like a circular saw). Then it occurred to me that not being a circle, the blade movement wouldn't really be measured in RPMs.

So I was trying to think what it *would* be measured in, and I realized it is moving up and down, oscillating, essentially like a wave... so thought maybe it would be measured in Hertz?

I looked up measures of frequency, and [this article](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/what_is_frequency_measured_in) says that Hertz apply to physical waves such as sound (as well as EM waves). Technically this is not actually a sine wave, but it is essentially an oscillating movement.

So I was just wondering, would Hertz be the correct unit of measure for the movement of the blade on a scroll saw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the Hertz unit is the correct unit to use.  Hertz is a measure of oscillatory phenomena in

$$\frac{\mathrm{cycles}}{\mathrm{second}}$$

It doesn't matter that your scroll saw doesn't trace out a perfect sine wave, it's still oscillatory and Hertz is the right unit to measure that.

The [Wikipedia article spells this out is better detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz) and uses a heart beat as an example of non-sinusoidal oscillation that can be measured in Hertz.

Comment: Technically $\mathrm{Hz}$ is $s^{-1}$ (inverse seconds) however cycles per second is the easiest way to understand the unit.

Comment: And the convention in physics is that $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$ is usually understood to mean radians per second rather than cycles per second.

Comment: Hmm, technically, if Hz is simply cycles/second, then Hz could - *technically* - be used to describe the motion of a circular saw too, couldn't it? With the "cycle" simply being defined as one complete revolution of the saw blade?

Comment: @eidylon yes however $\mathrm{Hz}$ applied to rotation is usually in radians per second (typically just $\omega$).